# Coding an Android app with a timeline and text stream

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android app to share text data in it's timeline. It will be like a mini-Twitter which I will be the one that writes and the users will just read it. So to make this possible I assume I need a server to distribute my texts to my users as soon as I'm done writing them. And here the problem begins. I don't have an idea about how to make this text stream thing happen. What kind of server do I need? How can I add new text data to server to share with my users? Or is there any other way to deal with this on Android?
I'm trying to learn coding on my own.
So if you can tell me where to look to solve this problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server with a database. You feed the database (ex. mysql) with information and you build a restful api around it. For this you can use a server side language to build the API, like PHP acompanied with an API building framework, like Slim.
Take a look here: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/)

For the client side you can either use a view that when the user refreshes it the new messages appear or you can use a Cloud Messaging Server, like Firebase. Take a look here: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.